# How to use reflection and abstract objects to dynamically load classes?

Tags: c#, oop, dynamic, reflection

I'm building a protocol handler. The protocol may support an unknown set of request types, and I will have a single class that implements each request type. These request handler classes will extend a base handler class. I'm trying to build the system such that in order to support a new request type, all I need to do is add a class for that and recompile/deploy/restart the service.

So I have something like this:

```cs
foreach (Type classType in protocolAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (classType.BaseType == typeof(ProtocolRequestHandler))
    {
        if (supportedRequestsMap.Contains(classType.Method))
        {
            // error: that method is already implemented!
        }

        supportedRequestsMap.Add(classType.Method, typeof(classType));
    }
}
```

Adding a new class is picked up when the service restarts, *as long as the request method it handles is declared.*

How can I enforce at compile time through through the base class **ProtocolRequestHandler** that property **Method** will be implemented? I don't want to use a method type as "Null" or "Unknown", or throw exceptions, and I don't want to specify the supported protocol request type inherently in the name of the extending classes (I would like to call the classes whatever I like).

Is there some way I can enforce that a property has its value set in an inheriting class?

Is there a cleaner way I can do this kind of dynamic loading? Should I be using attributes to determine the supported method of the inheriting class?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should rely on interfaces as a contract of what methods that should be implemented by your plugins.
A (little old, but still very relevant) nice tutorial can be found on [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4691/Plugin-Architecture-using-C)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought properties wouldn't work with interfaces. Once I knew what to look for, I found clear guidance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64syzecx(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a base class, why don't you just create your required method as an abstract method (or virtual and specify a default implementation if possible).  This will ensure that the method exists in your inherited class.  I believe you probably already know this if you are into reflection and writing your own protocol handler, but am not sure there is a better way to get what you want.

Comment: Yep, I was hoping to avoid this, just because implementing a method in each class to return a fixed string seems like boilerplate. Even using a property by way of an interface isn't all that nice. It would be nice if I could use attributes, and enforce at compile time that certain attributes exist (i might go investigate this now just for interests sake).

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing what you come up with going down the attribute route, please do edit the post if you find a nice pattern.